# Can the user profile's reputation tab distinguish between upvotes on questions vs answers?

Tags: feature-request, design, profile-page, reputation-history

**TL;DR**

Is it possible to clarify if a reputation change on the user reputation tab was for a question or an answer?

**Long Story**

I just tricked myself into believing [an answer by me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59375124/how-to-use-system-hashcode-combine-with-more-than-8-values) is being serial upvoted, as I constantly received double upvote notifications about it, and checking my user reputation tab, I always saw this:

[image: User Reputation Tab history]

Thus I thought some bot is double upvoting my answer, or some system is trying to test getting around serial upvoting detection - which made me flag it for moderator attention.

...then I realized that I've posted an answer to *my own* question there, and the upvotes were merely cast for both the answer *and* the question.

This was not clear on the reputation tab. I could only confirm this realization by looking at the post's vote history.

It would've helped me to see what kind of post the vote was casted for, like in this mockup, using a display similar to the Bookmarks on the profile Summary tab:

[image: User Reputation Tab history mockup]

Comment: I'm a little torn, because as proposed this would probably add a fair amount of clutter to the view. I say this because the vast, _vast_ majority of items in that list are answers; as far as I can tell the only case where you can ever gain/ lose reputation on a question and have it show up in the list would be where the question is your own. In all other cases (except maybe bountying a question?), those items will _all_ be answers, I think.

Comment: Also worth adding that, in theory, this would be a really straightforward userscript, given that the link format is different between questions and answers, making automatic recognition a piece of cake.

Comment: @zcoop98 well, given that the ratio of questions to answers varies greatly depending on the user, I'd say it is far from guaranteed that the tab will contain mostly rep earned / lost from answering. There is an additonal issue that there is no indication that the entry is an answer, which is, frankly, a confusing UI.

Comment: It is, indeed, easer to make a straightforward userscript for that, and I'll likely make one, but it would be nice to have natively (methinks, the problem of decluttering is just a mattr of using outlined icons instead of filled), so I consider this to be a valid feature request (not that I have any hope of it being implemented, as usual).

Comment: @OlegValteriswithUkraine That's a fair point; a user who doesn't do a lot of curating but does a lot of asking will probably have a mix more slanted towards questions, you're totally right.

Comment: @zcoop98 yeah, definitely :) Sometimes it's good to know one's bias - I can discern my only 3 questions pretty easily too, but it might not be true for others.

Comment: Or the next time you look at your user CP and you fall in the trap of assuming voting fraud based on an observation in an imperfect UI... kick yourself :)

Comment: @zcoop98 Clutter? This is basic information necessary for the UI to be useful and comprehensible. It's not like OP is suggesting adding flashing lolcat gif backgrounds to every UI element here, this is about making information critical to the UI visible

Comment: This information is already available in each line. A) The tooltip for the "upvote" text tells you if it's an answer or a question. B) When hovering over the link to the post, your browser should show you the URL for the post, or have some other type of preview for the URL before you actually navigate to it. The URLs for questions and answers are substantially different.

Comment: While yeah, one can distinguish between entries with a bit of effort as you've described, @Makyen, I think it would be better if the UI provided a proper way to discern them without resorting to URL inspection or hovering (not available on touch devices as you know) :)

Comment: @Makyen Thanks for pointing out the tooltips telling which line is what - but I would have never checked without you saying where to point my cursor exactly, especially since it's not the whole line having the tooltip! (Inb4, I should've posted this on meta.stackexchange, as it isn't specific to just StackOverflow.)

Comment: I like the proposed design. It seems quite unobtrusive to me. A bit of visual noise for those who don't care, useful information for those who do.

Comment: Complexly novel idea: one could make the reward for answer and question upvotes slightly different, say 10 points for an answer and 5 points for a question and suddenly the problem wouldn't exist :)

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz but downvotes still cost the same for both! Make it -5 for answers then! (yes, this question asks explicitly about upvotes, but this case also applies to downvotes on self-answered Q&A)

Comment: @AndrewT. -5 sounds good -- maybe this will stop random guess answers :)

Answer (score 17):

I didn't realise just how unclear the reputation page is with regard to post type until it was different. It would be great if this were implemented natively within the UI so that all users can benefit from something like this.

In the meantime, for of us who use UserScripts, I've put together a small script ([Stack Apps post](https://stackapps.com/q/9503/86271)) which implements something similar to the initial proposal.

---

Here's what it looks like:

[image: Reputation page on Stack Overflow with Q and A Stacks Icons before each link]

This also functions as expected for reputation earned from suggested edits:

[image: Reputation page on Stack Overflow with Q and A Stacks Icons before each link. Approved suggested edits are also annotated with appropriate post types]

**Installation:**

1. Install a UserScript manager
2. Add the UserScript to your manager [install link](https://github.com/HenryEcker/SO-UserScripts/raw/main/QuestionAnswerIconsOnReputationHistory.user.js) ([GitHub Source](https://github.com/HenryEcker/SO-UserScripts/blob/main/QuestionAnswerIconsOnReputationHistory.user.js))